# PNS error when sending push notification to registered Android device

Tags: android, azure, azure-notificationhub

I am setting up a service to send push notifications to our apps using an Azure Notification Hub. Registering the android device works fine (shows up correctly in VS 2015 Azure tools) but when I try and send a test post through the Azure portal or the VS 2015 Test Send tool I get the error "The Push Notification System handle for the registration is invalid" and the registration is deleted. I understand that when the notification hub gets an error it deletes the registration so that part makes sense. I can't find any info on why the PNS would be invalid. My registration code is:

```
public class PushRegObject
{
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string Handle { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}

public async static Task<ObjectResultObject<string>> RegisterDevice(PushRegObject reg)
{
    string newRegistrationID = null;

    var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(_connectionstring_, _name_);

    if (reg.Handle != null)
    {
        // Get the Registration ID
        var registrations = await hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(reg.Handle, 100);
        foreach(var registration in registrations)
        {
            if (newRegistrationID == null)
                newRegistrationID = registration.RegistrationId;
            else
                await hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registration);
        }

        if (newRegistrationID == null)
            newRegistrationID = await hub.CreateRegistrationIdAsync();

        // Register the Device
        RegistrationDescription regObj = null;
        switch (reg.Platform)
        {
            case "android":
                var regDesc = await hub.CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync(newRegistrationID);
                return new ObjectResultObject<string>(true, null) { Object = regDesc.GcmRegistrationId };
            case "ios":
                regObj = new AppleRegistrationDescription(reg.Handle);
                break;
            default:
                return new ObjectResultObject<string>(false, "Unknown device type");
        }
    }

    return new ObjectResultObject<string>(true, null) { Object = newRegistrationID };
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update**
With the help of Dmitry in narrowing down the problem, I found the solution which was to use the full token return from GCM in the CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync call.

```
var regDesc = await hub.CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync(reg.Handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason, my name is Dmitry and I work in Notification Hubs team. Below are a few steps that will help us to troubleshoot this issue.

1. Use `NotificationHubClient.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(100)` to get all your registrations from the notification hub, find the registration from your test android device there and compare the GcmRegistrationId of this registration with the actual registration id which device recieves from GCM.
2. If the registration ids on the previous step are equal, then make sure that you uploaded the correct GCM API Key to the notification hub.
3. If GCM credentials in the notification hub are correct, then try to send a notification to your device using some third-party tools, for example cURL and command line as Google suggests here - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07?hl=en. Make sure that you use the same API Key, that was configured in the notification hub, and registration id, that was uploaded into the notification hub.
4. If you were able to successfully send a notification to your device using a third-party tool, then please send namespace and notification hub name to nhubsupport@microsoft.com and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the response! In step 1, how would I identify my device from the list of registrations returned? The only thing I have to match is the registration ID which seems to be what you suggest comparing next.

Comment: Correct, you can use RegistrationId for matching. In your example you get a registration id for a new registration using this code `newRegistrationID = await hub.CreateRegistrationIdAsync();`. You need to find a registration from a collection returned by `NotificationHubClient.GetAllRegistrationsAsync()` with the same registration id and compare GCM registration id, which you got on the device, with the GCM registration id from this registration.
To get GCM registration id from the RegistrationDescription you need to cast it to the GcmRegistrationDescription first.

Comment: Hmm, the format of the token I'm receiving from GCM looks nothing like the registration ID that shows up in VS. My token looks like this "f4tj7SohUls:APA91bElcRByfB4bzxuLI-8ZmSSGPwxvIXIfGZwLaVrRCzGNeINGxuGSaKObfPZRhGCGCJWDdBh-CSwTnSkaS4ExBBkp_rjHsshJGvxF0eq1gfNWHcTQx5-LtJAe6fnnXsAbnnTueuWW" and the reg ID looks like "6654254519046612901-5384268793895935544-1". If it means anything, I'm using the phonegap-plugin-push plugin for Cordova to get the token.

Comment: The first alphanumeric string - it is a GCM registration ID, the device received it from Google. The second numeric string - is a Notification Hub's internal identifier for a device registration, device received it from Hotification Hub backend and your application used it to create a new device registration in your notification hub. This alphanumeric string looks good, so I think you can skip step 1 and do step 2.

Comment: I think there is a confusion with the term "registration id". Notification Hub identifies device registrations using a string and this string is called _registration ID_. Each device registration contains a device handle received from the according Push Notification System (PNS) - WNS (Microsoft), GCM (Google), APNS (Apple), etc. Each PNS has its own name for a device handle: WNS calls it _channel URI_, GCM - _registration ID_, APNS - _device token_. Now you can see why it is easy to get confused - Notufication Hub and GCM's identifiers are called the same - _registration ID_.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Dmitry. I was able to successfully send a notification to the device using the curl command from that article you linked. I'm sending the info you requested to your e-mail. Thanks again!